# Furnace Firing Issue

Tags: hvac

Having some trouble with intermittent firing on my furnace. Three times this week I have had to go and manually reset it. Has been an issue for two heating
Go seasons now with multiple folks coming to look at it. Specifics - Bard FLR140D60e model, oil fired. Running a two year old Genisys 7505 control unit, problem predates the install of the new unit. Regularly serviced and filters replaced. Troubleshooting to date. New control unit, replaced blower fan thinking perhaps air flow was an issue, electrical diagnostics from the mother board all check, igniter fan shows no signs of failure, high limit switch replaced, fire eye check and positioned, new nozzles on multiple occasions. Everything turns on but never fires just continues to blow cold air until you hit the reset on the control and it fires right up. A new for me was it was not starting and on a whim I opened the fire box door and when it slammed close it reset itself and fired right up. Not sure what do look at next. Any suggestions.

Comment: What is a "heating Go season"? While you're [edit]ing to fix that, please add in some line breaks and formatting, it will make reading your question much easier. You seem to have the majority of details folks will need to get you an answer, but they're just buried in in a big wall of text and that makes them hard to find.

Comment: Regularly serviced by...? You, or a licensed oil burner service tech?